# Breakpoints in Provides method get remapped in Eclipse to ProvidesAdapter instead

Tags: eclipse, dependency-injection, breakpoints, dagger

I am having an issue in Eclipse (with Dagger 1 still).

In dagger, for dependency injection (javax.inject), you create a Module class, with provides methods, like this:

```
@dagger.Module
class FooModule {
  @dagger.Provides
  Something provideSomething() {
    return new Something();
  }
}
```

And this will generate a class (using annotation processing) called `FooModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideSomethingProvidesAdapter`.

If I set a breakpoint in a `provideSomething` method in `FooModule` class (my code), Eclipse almost always actually stops on that same line number in the `FooModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideSomethingProvidesAdapter` class instead.

Does anyone know how to avoid this problem?  I suspect this is likely an Eclipse issue where it is somehow is mapping the generated file to what it thinks is the "source" file, but that's of course not what I want.

Is there perhaps some setting in eclipse to avoid this problem?

Comment: Probably seeing some code involved would help give context. I, for one, have no idea what Dagger, ModulkeAdapter, provide*, etc. are

Comment: I added some sample code, but if you want to know more about dagger see http://square.github.io/dagger/

Comment: The eclipse preference under Java | Compiler, "Add source file name to generated class file (used by the debugger)", was one thought - but that removes the association between all class files, which is definitely not what I want to do.